# I have three strings and I want to align them

Tags: python, python-3.x, join, format

I have three strings: `s1`, `s2`, and `edit action`. They are given below:

```
s1 = kevin josh left at three for - car.
s2 = kevin - left at one - for his car.
edit action =  d      s   i
```

I want to align them like this:

```
s1          = kevin josh left at three for  -  car.
s2          = kevin  -   left at  one  for his car.
edit action =        d             s        i
```

Below is my code where I have used format and join to align them     together:

```py
print(" s1 = ", '{0}'.format(" ".join(s1)))
print(" s2 = ",'{0}'.format(" ".join(s2)))
print("edit action = ",'{0}'.format(" ".join(edit action)))
```

Comment: How are `d`, `s`, and `i` related to `josh` and `-`, `three` and `one`, and `-` and `his`?

Comment: They are the operations needed to convert string s1 to string s2. d stands for deletion of a word, s stands or substitution of a word and i stands for insertion of a word.

Answer (score 1):

```
s1 = "kevin josh left at three for - car."
s2 = "kevin - left at one - for his car."
editaction = "  d      s   i".replace(" ","")
maxstring=max(len(s1),len(s2))
c1=len("edit action ")
c2='{:'+str(c1)+'}  {:'+str(maxstring)+'} ' 
print(c2.format(" s1 ", "= "+s1))
print(c2.format(" s2 ", "= "+s2))
w1=s2.find("-") #d
w2=s2.find("one")-w1 #s
w3=s2.find("his")-w2-w1  #i
print(c2.format(" edit action","= " +
editaction.replace(editaction[0]," "*w1+editaction[0]).replace(editaction[1]," 
"*w2+editaction[1]).replace(editaction[2]," "*w3+editaction[2])))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following format specifier, from [the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples):

```
'{:>max_width}'.format('right aligned')
```

where `max_width` can be chosen as the length of the longest left hand side.